# How can I remove some folders from the output file using the maven assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create a zip file out of a structure of files. For this I am using the maven assembly plugin:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${reporting.module.zip.name}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

and an assembly descriptor file:

```
    <id>zip</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>        
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

Good...so this is the setup...what is my problem ?
Well, the problem is that the zip file contains the folders "src\main\resources" and then the files that I wanted inside the zip. I would like these files to be on the first level inside the zip file...

**So intead of "my.zip -> src -> main -> resources -> my files" I would like to have "my.zip -> my files".**

I was looking through http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html but could not find any element that could help me..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer...

You need to put `<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>` in the assembly descriptor file..

```
<id>zip</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>        
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```